# Escape special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, special-characters

```html
$.ajax({
  url: "/Search/GetMatchCount?idx=" + idx + "&q=" + escape(q) + "&filter=" + escape(filter) + "&fields=" + fields,
  success: function (data) {
    $("#tabprograms").html("Customer Programs (" + data + ")");
  }
});
```

I have a string "civic+governance" in my search text-box.

I want to retrieve the value of the text-box in some local variable with jquery/javascript.  My code is,

```
var q = document.getElementById('q').value;
```

The value that I get for q is "civic governance".
The '+' sign seems to be encoded with " ".

How do I not make it encoded to " " and have my string as it is , i.e. "civic+governance".

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/9c8smu9j/. Value contains `+`. Something else must be at works that replaces the `+`. The DOM API doesn't do this by itself.

Comment: you must be passing the string through a regex function of some type

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using ESCAPE(q). ESCAPE can not encode the + character you need to use the encodeURIComponent(q) then decode in php with rawurldecode() or you could also change your method to POST.

Comment: <input type="search" class="form-control" name="q" id="q" value="civic+governanace" area-label="..." autocomplete="off" size="160" placeholder="Enter search keywords"> this is my code and i am using the following in javascript file ,  var q = document.getElementById('q').value;

Comment: to add, i am using chrome.

Comment: in the alert box, it gives me civic+governance. but when i add a watch for q, it shows the value for q as civic governance

Comment: The string contains the plus sign even if chromes variable watch says it doesn't. as you could tell by alerting the variable.

Comment: but, futher when i make an ajax call using this q as a parameter, the call is constructed with the keyword as civic+governance rather than civic+governance

Comment: please include code in a snippet above to show anywhere that this is occuring! the ONLY explination is it is being passed through a regex or you are using a GET method in which URLs use + as a space character. we NEED your FULL code in order to assist you. without it we are taking shots in the dark and wasting our time along with yours.

Comment: I am using a GET method. here is the code from .js file
var q = document.getElementById('q').value;
alert(q);
}
</script>

Comment: The only way you can use GET with the + sign is a regex to change it to something else from javascript then a regex to change it back to + in php. this is because + will be " " after parsed out of a URL. the simplest solution would be to change to POST method

Comment: Where is your AJAX call this code is simply showing the value in a alert box!

Comment: $.ajax({
                    url: "/Search/SomeMethodName inController?idx=" + idx + "&q=" + q + "&filter=" + escape(filter) + "&fields=" + fields,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("XXXXXXX").html("Somevalue (" + data + ")");
                    }
                });

Comment: i have provided, the js code with the ajax call, i think there is some problem with ajax call because till the ajax call is not made, q has + symbol, after ajax call is made, q has " " instead of +. Please suggest.

Comment: please edit your original post to include ALL code in a code snippet or fiddle. Include your JS(WITH the ajax call you were reffering to) and the PHP or ASP code handling the server-side processing) and anything else that may be able to help us to help you

Comment: var q = $('#q').val().replace(new RegExp("\\+", "g"),
        '+'

Comment: used this regex also, but no luck!

Comment: Check my edit above you need to change your encoding from escape(q) to encodeURIComponent(q)

Comment: An please in the future start off by including everything we need to debug your code in the original post and we would have found the mestake in your code earlier and wasted less time

Comment: Thank Tou . this helped. sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: It's no problem. Just in future please help us to help you and just include the code. Please select my answer as correct answer and vote up.  Thank you